# CDU delegates will vote on German coalition proposal; SPD members have started voting; will there be a vote in the CSU too?

Tags: germany

A proposal has been made by the leaderships of three German political parties, the CDU (Christian Democratic Union), SPD (Social Democratic Party), and CSU (Christian Social Union - the CDU's sister party in Bavaria) that they should form a coalition government.

A vote will be taken on the proposal at the CDU's conference on 25 February 2018.

Voting is currently underway among the members of the SPD, the result of which is expected to be announced on 4 March 2018.

What about the CSU? Does that party also have a procedure whereby the proposed coalition agreement must be ratified or rejected by delegates or members, and if so what is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to *Deutsche Welle*](http://www.dw.com/de/csu-sagt-ja-zum-koalitionsvertrag/a-42510703), the coalition agreement was on behalf of CSU already accepted by three party bodies: the CSU representatives in the federal parliament (*Landesgruppe*), the CSU representatives in the Bavarian parliament, and the party’s executive committee. There won’t be a convention, nor will there be a poll among party members at large.